# Animate ListView Item with variable height (wrap_content)

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I know loads of articles describe how to animate the expansion/collapse of a listView item but I simply cannot get it working :-(

I have a listView where each item contains a hidden LinearLayout element ll (View.GONE) and I would like to expand/collapse ll using an animation. My problem is - apparently - the variable height of ll. ll's height is set to wrap_content as it contains a description and some images.

The challenge as I see it it the fact that I start out with ll's viibility set to View.GONE. If I change it to View.VISIBLE before starting the animation the area expands instantly and the text animates down. If I change visibility after the animation I don't get the animation effect.

Here's a snippet from my onItemClickListener:

```
LinearLayout llMatchInfo = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.matchInfo); 
//llMatchInfo.setVisibility(llMatchInfo.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, (llMatchInfo.getHeight() == 0) ? R.anim.down_from_top : R.anim.up_from_bottom);
llMatchInfo.startAnimation(animation);
```

Can anyone shed some light as to how to accomplish animating an element with height wrap_content and initial visibility View.GONE?

I'm really sorry if I've missed an obvious answer but I just feel like I've tried everything... :-/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:

https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout

It can save your life and time.
It's easy, you need only add the custom listview on your layout, create the adapter with customs implementations, setAdapter and voalá.

I just tried to help...

Comment: Suggesting to use a library should be a last resort for something this simple

Comment: I know... But the life is not so easy my friend.